# Qual é a origem e história do aumentativo “-ão”?

Tags: etimologia, sufixos

Atualmente nós podemos juntar *-ão* a basicamente qualquer nome para dar a noção de grande: *montão, tempão, casacão, passarão*, etc. Até mesmo com certos adjetivos: *lindão, bonitão*. Mas donde é que isto vem. Quando é que começou?

Eu sei que muitas das nossas palavras em *-ão* vêm de palavras latinas em *-anum: manum → mão, germanum → irmão, sanum → são* (’saudável’). A evolução é bem conhecida: o *-m* final caiu, e o *-n-* intervocálico nasalou a voga anterior e caiu. Também temos *-ão* vindo de *-anem* (*canem → cão*) e de *-onem* (*saponem → sabão*). Mas nada disto explica como é que *-ao* dá a noção de grande.

**Então eu gostaria de saber é:**

1. Quais são os exemplos mais antigos do *-ão* aumentativo na língua portuguesa?
2. É a forma original, ou veio de uma forma anterior? Por exemplo, creio que há palavras atuais em *-ão* que no português antigo eram em *-om*, mas não sei se eram aumentativos.
3. Quando é que se generalizou o uso de *-ão* como aumentativo?
4. Isto já tem raízes no latim (ou noutra língua)? Isto é, o *anum*, *-anem*, *-onem* ou outros já eram aumentativos?

Comment: ... e porque será que canem não virou cãe, e saponem não virou sabõe? 

Comment: @ANeves, perguntas bem! O plural é que ficou certinho (*canes, sapones*).

Comment: Ótima pergunta, incrível que não tivesse sido feita ainda.

Comment: @stafusa, o peixe não pergunta donde vem a água... :)

Answer (score 2):

O aumentativo *-ão* tem como cognatos e sinônimos *-ón* do espanhol, *-one* do italiano, *-on* do francês, e vem do latim "-ō, -ōnis" (m.). (Não confundir com o sufixo feminino idêntico que forma nomes abstratos como *actiō* "ação".) Segundo [1] (da pg. 163, traduzido abaixo):

> *-ón* é um sufixo de dupla origem. Em primeiro lugar, procede de *-ō, -ōnis*, sufixo que deriva nomes de grupos de pessoas a partir de verbos (*errō, -ōnis* "vagabundo" ← *errāre* "vagar") e substantivos (*buccō, -ōnis* "tagarela" ← *bucca, -ae* "boca"). [...] Em castelhano converteu-se, no primeiro dos casos, num sufixo aumentativo. [...]

Outros exemplos do latim [2]:

- *capitō* (quem tem cabeça grande) ← *caput, capitis*;
- *comedō* (guloso) ← *comedō* (v.);
- *congerō* (ladrão) ← *congerō* (v., levar junto);
- *cōnsedō* (quem senta junto a outro) ← *cōnsedō* (v.);
- *decuriō* (decurião) ← *decuria*;
- *incubō* (quem deita em cima) ← *incubō* (v.);
- *labeō*/*labiō* (quem tem lábio grande) ← *labium*;
- *mūliō* (quem anda de mula) ← *mūlus*;
- *palpō* (bajulador) ← *palpō* (v., palpar);
- *pedō* (quem tem pé largo) ← *pēs, pedis*;
- *praedō* (ladrão) ← *praeda*;
- *restiō* (vendedor de corda) ← *restis*;
- *verberō* (quem merece ser surrado) ← *verberō* (v.).

Porém, não encontrei um que fosse aumentativo literal (por exemplo, *pedō* não é literalmente um pé largo, mas *quem tem* um pé largo), exceto talvez [cōleō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coleo#Latin) (século 8). Mesmo assim, acho que grande parte do latim vulgar usava esse sufixo também como aumentativo literal porque:

- Os significados são similares.
- Até o romeno, uma das línguas românicas mais distantes do português, tem o aumentativo cognato sinônimo [-oi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-oi#Romanian).

Na língua portuguesa antiga escrita, encontrei [galeón](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/galeon#Old_Galician-Portuguese) (galé grande), usado desde o século 13 ou até antes. Também, *coraçón* (bem mais antiga) *talvez* fosse originalmente um aumentativo. [3] Resta procurar quando o sufixo começou a ser usado com adjetivos.

Já o sufixo latino *-ānus* forma adjetivos (*Rōma* → *Rōmānus*), não aumentativos. Não há sufixo *-anis/ānis* em latim.

Referências.

[1]. [https://revistadefilologiaespañola.revistas.csic.es/index.php/rfe/article/view/101](https://xn--revistadefilologiaespaola-uoc.revistas.csic.es/index.php/rfe/article/view/101)

[2]. https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text.jsp?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059, insira as palavras.

[3]. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/coraceonem, citando o dicionário etimológico de Coromines e Pascual.

Obs para ANeves: No português antigo e no espanhol atual é *can* (sem o *e* final), por isso que se tornou *cão* não **cãe*.